# Resolving relative urls in nested style files with postcss & scss

Tags: webpack, sass, postcss, css-loader, postcss-loader

I'm using postcss with scss synthax to organize styles in project. The simplified structure listed below:

```
client
  media
    images
      image.png
  styles
    index.scss
    components
      component1.scss
```

Entry point for Webpack loaders is client/styles/index.scss.

If I define some style with url() statement with relative path to image.png - like url('../media/images/image.png') (for example - in background-image property) in index.scss it will be resolved fine.

But if I do same thing in nested style file - styles/components/component1.scss - url('../../media/images/image.png') which is imported by index.scss — Webpack will throw an error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../media/images/image.png' in '/Users/anubis/Projects/Jackal/client/styles'
```

Seems that loader treat relative urls in all nested files with entry style file path. How to change this behavior?

```js
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: [
    { loader: 'style-loader' },
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        importLoaders: 1,
        sourceMap: true,
        minimize: true
      }
    },
    {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {
        ident: 'postcss',
        parser: scssParser,
        sourceMap: true,
        plugins: () => [
          require('precss')({
            import: {
              resolve: styleFileResolver
            }
          }),
          require('postcss-font-magician')({
            hosted: ['./client/media/fonts/OpenSans']
          }),
          require('postcss-short')(),
          require('postcss-cssnext')(),
          require('postcss-utilities')()
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `resolve-url-loader`. You can try adding it between css and postcss loaders

Comment: Yeah, it helped me. I also switched to sass-loader and keep postcss only for autoprefix, css-mqpacker and cssnano.

Working pipeline is now `style-loader < css-loader < postcss-loader < resolve-url-loader < sass-loader`